# Hard things about Russian

Tags: лингвистика

What are the most notorious things for which Russian is known as one of the hardest to learn?

Comment: It probably depends a lot on your native language.

Comment: Obviously, especially if your native language is Russian

Comment: Possibly, comma placement.

Comment: I guess aspect and the missing article, since Germanic and Romance languages (at least those I know) don't have aspect but articles.

Comment: 1) Case. 2) Aspect. 3) Pretty much everything else in the language. (I keep a running list -- in my head -- of topics that are *not* hard in Russian. I have come up with only a few. "Alphabet" is one. "Order of alphabet" is another. Many times I have been tempted to add "word order," but that is actually really hard.) Udachi!

Comment: ...."Names of letters" is another, with some exceptions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Alphabet. It's not Latin, people spend a week or so to only remember that P is not [p], but [r].
2. Aspect. It is formed irregularly, it has tons of minor meanings, and the exact interpretation depends on certain properties of the verb meaning. And it also depends on prefixes.
3. Inflection. You have to learn large paradigms only to be able to say a short sentence.
4. Rich derivation. You can form many words just by adding suffixes.
5. Word order. It is not free, as some people say, but it encodes the information structure of the sentence.
6. Phonology. Quality of vowels changes depending on the stress in the word (which is also not always fixed), voiced consonants become voiceless depending on the following consonant or on the position in the word.

Finally, Russian is not as hard to learn as Welsh or Hungarian. But not many people want to learn these languages (for some reason), and that may be another reason why they focus on Russian and say it's hard. It probably wouldn't be so hard in comparison =)

Comment: could you please clarify the point about spoken vs. written?

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: are you sure it's specific to Russian?

Comment: Maybe not, maybe spoken French is also different from written French. But it's still one of the things why Russian may be considered hard.

Comment: sure, but it's in no way is specific to Russian. Actually it's just whether you pay attention to your discourse or not. There are people who actually write like in your first example (especially in IM or twits or whatever) and there are people who don't ever talk this, not to mention writing. If the language structure allows comprehending an ungrammar sentence at all, there will always be people abusing grammar.

Comment: Is there a way to move it to chat? It's interesting, I'd like to discuss it, but it is not the topic of the question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4142/discussion-between-quassnoi-and-olga)

Comment: its ok, you may discuss it in here, i dont mind

Comment: As a native Russian speaker, I could not make head nor tail of the example sentence in point 7.

Comment: @kotekzot come to chat =)

Comment: OK, since people don't like the last point and I have to argue about it, I will remove it. There are enough other things that are hard about Russian) I'll move it to the chat untouched, so that we can all see and discuss it, if we want.

Comment: Personally I don't have a problem with point 7, just with the example.

Comment: Alphabet is not difficult to any Russian speaker. And I doubt it is difficult at all.

Comment: Phonology is also not difficult for Russian speakers. The question asks about problems for NATIVE Russian speakers.

Comment: @Anixx Why do you think so? For me, the question sounds as "why Russian is hard to learn"

Comment: See the second comment to the question.

Comment: I don't think the question is asking about what makes the language hard for native speakers; the second comment seems more like a humorous response to the first comment than a clarification of the intent of the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the difficulties for a native Russian speaker, they are as follows:

- Comma placement rules
- Whether participle не- is written together with the following word or not.
- Whether н is double in suffixes (choice between нн and н).
- Some people experience troubles in choice between -тся and -ться although this is not a problem for myself.

Answer (score 1):

1. Inflections, especially the **cases** and **verb conjugations**. Also the **number** and **gender**.
2. Pronunciation of certain sounds non-existent in languages like English. That includes the vowel sound of **Ы** [ɨ], all palatalized consonants, and rolling the **Р** [r]. Also, the chains of consonants as in "**вздр**огнуть".
3. Stress in words. It's mostly unpredictable in Russian and you'll have to refer to your dictionary a lot.

Comment: Actually I find the two most difficult...I mean that you must force yourself to pronounce properly to be ы and ль ... rolling Р is not (for me.. .ever a problem. . I'm a native English speaker but not American. .. I noticed for some reason most Americans have problems when two constants are together.they want to say them as separate words... can't think of any examples offhand but I think some people know what I'm talking about )

Answer (score 1):

You can easily yandex it up yourslef, as follows:

1. go to yandex.ru, which is better than google for Russian searches
2. Search "типичные ошибки в русском языке у американцев"

Wikipedia says" According to Yandex marketing, one of its biggest advantages for Russian-language users is ability to recognize the Russian inflection in search queries

Comment: who said yandex is better?

Comment: @v'-5o-1's73- it's common knowledge. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yandex#Market_share

Comment: I don't want to hurt anyone's feelings, but having larger audience doesn't mean it's better

Answer (score 0):

7 падежей. В других языках нет такого количества падежей и даже представления о том, что они могут существовать.

And as we can see many foreigners don't even use them. They only use one case for speaking.

Comment: [Finnish cases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finnish_grammar#Noun_forms) rock even more.

Comment: In addition, example on typical using of russian language by vietnamese in Russia: "Мне пожалуйста вон тот большой ваза". Correct variant: "Мне пожалуйста вон ту большую вазу"

Comment: @Rustam: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsez_language, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabasaran_language

Comment: Many languages have the same or greater amount of cases.

Comment: падежы сложны, но в других языках бывает и поболее.